# Scrapy yield response object in start_request method

Tags: python, scrapy, generator

I have a simple code in Scrapy -

```
def start_requests(self):
    response = scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_response)
    response.meta['some_useful_params'] = some_useful_params
    yield response

def parse_respone(self,resposne):
    some_useful_params = response.meta['some_useful_params']
    do_parsing_stuff()
    if some_conditon==True:
        presponse = scrapy.Request(otherurl,callback=self.parse_response)
        presponse.meta['some_useful_params'] = some_useful_params
        yield presponse
    else:
        yield items
```

The above program works fine for me, but I need to change it to something that will check if the html already exists for that page, then take that as html rather than making request to the website.

Now the code for that -

```
def start_requests(self):
    if html_exist:
        request = scrapy.Request(url)
        request.meta['some_useful_params'] = some_useful_params
        response = scrapy.http.Response(url,body=cached_html,request=request)
        #the below line doesn't call the method parse_response
        self.parse_response(response)
    else:
        response = scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_response)
        response.meta['some_useful_params'] = some_useful_params
        yield response

def parse_respone(self,resposne):
    some_useful_params = response.meta['some_useful_params']
    do_parsing_stuff()
    if some_conditon==True:
        if html_exist:
            request = scrapy.Request(url)
            request.meta['some_useful_params'] = some_useful_params
            presponse = scrapy.http.Response(url,body=cached_html,request=request)
            #the below line doesn't call the method parse_response
            self.parse_response(presponse)
        else:
            presponse = scrapy.Request(otherurl,callback=self.parse_response)
            presponse.meta['some_useful_params'] = some_useful_params
            yield presponse
    else:
        yield items
```

The problem I am facing is in the second code, if html exits, call to parse_response method does not happen.

Although I don't understand the reason completely but I think it is something related to Python generators, how can I resolve this issue.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to yield the `items` or `requests`, not just call the method:

```
for item_or_request in self.parse_response(response):
    yield item_or_request
```

Comment: is there any way through which I can set the html(cache copy) to the request object instead of making a request to the website?

Comment: you can use the [`HttpCacheMiddleware`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache)